# AsynTask not run to onPostExcute after lock screen and wait 5 minute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a AsysTask

```
    class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {
        ProgressDialog progDialog;

        myAsyncTask() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                    SwitchArticle.this,
                    "Loading",
                    "Pleasewait",
                    true,
                    true,
                    new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            myAsyncTask.this.cancel(true);
                        }
                    }
            );
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... arg0) {            
            // Call a function load Data Json...

            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);     
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (result != 1) {
                progDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(
                        SwitchArticle.this,
                        "Error Load Data",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                //.. Bind Data To Adapter
            }
            progDialog.dismiss();
        }
}
```

Call in Oncreate function :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myAsyncTask ma = new myAsyncTask();
        ma.execute();       
    }
```

The first time, this code is load data and bind to listview very good.
then, i press back other activity,and comback this activity call asyntask, this code run very good.

After i back to other activity , and finish this activity call this asysntask. I press lock screen device and wait about 5 minute. i unlock device and come back activity call this asysntask. myAsynTask run `doInBackGround` and NOT run to `onPostExcute` to bind data to ListView.

Sorry because my English is very poor. I'm Vietnamese.

Answer (score 0):

I think onCreate is called when you unlock the screen and go back to your activity. That means your AsyncTask will start running again... Hope that helps